# Best practice to fill horizontal width in ConstraintLayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I need to make this design
[image]

Usually I create these kind of designs using `LinearLayout` but in this case its a list item so I  don't want to use nested linearLayouts.

I want to create this design in a single `ConstraintLayout`. But I am unable to find any solution where I will be able to give most of horizontal space to ProductTitle and some width to image and stock button.

I know we provide weights in LinearLayout but how I can achieve this in `ConstraintLayout` in such way that `if text is long enough then it should  not override/misplace the stock button`

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your problem correctly what you want to achieve is something like this

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dyGR.png)

The code is the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_dark_grey"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pretium, velit egestas fringilla congue, magna massa fringilla metus, nec fermentum nunc justo quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_dark_grey"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

But you want to break the line and show dots. This is very easy: just add this two attributes to the TextView

```
android:lines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

In this way you are saying to show only one line, while the ellipsis is used to show dots and break the text.

Answer (score 0):

set width to 0dp and give it constraints on both sides

```
<Imageview app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image" />
<Switch app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```